# C# Generic factory method does not call constructor as intended

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

So I have a type inherited from `Page`(2nd descendant: `CreationDialog : MainPage : Page`) with a parameterless constructor. I have a static generic factory method in the `PageFactory` class:

```
public static class PageFactory
{
    public static T GetInstance<T>(WebDriver driver) where T : Page, new()
    {

        T page = new T
        {
            Driver = driver
        };
        return page;
    }
}

public class Page 
{
public static T GetInstance<T>() where T : Page, new()
    {
        return PageFactory.GetInstance<T>(Utils.GetCurrentDriver());
    }
}

public class CreationDialog : MainPage, IModal
{
   public CreationDialog()
    {
        IModal _Modal = Modal.Get(WindowLocator);
    }

    IModal _Modal { get; set; }
}
```

`Modal.Get(WindowLocator)` is a static method with a static parameter.

The problem is - when I call `GetInstance<CreationDialog>()` I end up not initializing `_Modal` and a null reference exception when methods from `_Modal` are called later.

The debugger shows that when get instance is called the type parameter is correcly `CreationDialog`, so why doesn't it call its own constructor? What am I missing?

Update: a breakpoint in `CreationDialog` constructor is reached, but after the constructor is left back to method scope `page` variable is set to `null` and it is initialized with just the `driver`.

And who can I read on the subject as I can't seem to get constructors and inheritance right?

Comment: Are you certain the constructor isn't getting called?  It's possible that your code could be running the constructor, but `_Modal` is getting set to null.  Have you set a breakpoint in the constructor to confirm it's not being called?

Comment: @Amy Is there a way to check that? I can't seem to get from debugger what the compiler exactly means by `new T`

Comment: You can check it by setting a breakpoint in the constructor and running it to see if your debugger hits the breakpoint.  Or add a logging statement.  `new T()` just calls the constructor.  I think  `Modal.Get(WindowLocator);` is returning `null`, and you've drawn the wrong conclusion.

Comment: @Amy checked and it's very strange. When I set breakpoint in the constructor, it's reached all right, but when I leave that scope back to `GetInstance<T>` method page is set to `null` again. I'm really lost now, actually. Will update the question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us where you call `GetInstance`, you've stated you're using `GetInstance<T>()`, but you've given us the code for `GetInstance<T>(WebDriver driver)`.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller true, it's wrapped, missed it. Will add the wrapper to question.

Comment: Is _Modal really declared in the constructor? Did you miss showing us a class variable? private IModal _Modal perhaps?

Comment: Are you sure `Modal.Get(WindowLocator)` doesn't return null?

Comment: @DerrickMoeller it's there all right, added to question. I don't think it would compile otherwise with all the references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is local versus member scope.  Change this:

```
public class CreationDialog : MainPage, IModal
{
    public CreationDialog()
    {
        IModal _Modal = Modal.Get(WindowLocator);
    }

    IModal _Modal { get; set; }
}
```

To this:

```
public class CreationDialog : MainPage, IModal
{
    public CreationDialog()
    {
        _Modal = Modal.Get(WindowLocator);  //Don't declare new variable
    }

    IModal _Modal { get; set; }
}
```

Although this would be even better:

```
public class CreationDialog : MainPage, IModal
{
    protected readonly IModal _modal;

    public CreationDialog()
    {
        _modal = Modal.Get(WindowLocator);  //Don't declare new variable
    }

    public IModal Modal
    {
        get { return _modal; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring _Modal twice, once as a local variable and once as a property. You're assigning a value to the variable, to set the value of your property simply remove the type declaration.

```
public class CreationDialog : MainPage, IModal
{
    public CreationDialog()
    {
        _Modal = Modal.Get(WindowLocator);
    }

    IModal _Modal { get; set; }
}
```